# link-to works in index.hbs but not in application.hbs

Tags: ember.js

When I do a `{{#link-to "cars/category" "mini"}}` from `index.hbs`, everything works fine. I transition to `cars/category` -> `templates/cars/category.hbs`.

However, when I do the same from `application.hbs` (for navigation), I transition to an empty page and then automatically transition to the parent route `cars.index` -> `templates/cars/index.hbs`.

There is probably some logic to this. How can I transition to this route from a link click in `application.hbs`?

(a hard link `<a href="/cars/mini"` works fine, but I'll lose the state of the application.)

---

`routes/cars/category.js` model:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('cars/category', params.category_id, {backgroundReload: false});
}
```

---

In `route.js`:

```
this.route('cars', () => {
    this.route('cars/category', { path: '/cars/:category_id' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested that since I transition to the desired page and then immediately transition to its parent, there must have been some other transition queued.

On further inspection, the `link-to` was indeed inside a drop down menu of a list-item which itself was a `link-to` too.

The solution was to add `bubbles=false` to the inner `link-to`.

The other answers here doubt the used routes. However, they are fine and setup like this for a reason. E.g. multiple routes with a subroute called category cannot all be in the root. However, it was my fault for not disclosing the exact code which put people on the wrong track, for they would probably have noticed the actual problem immediately.

Next time I will be more verbose in my code. I apologize, and thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1):

For the below route.js

```
this.route('cars', function(){
    this.route('category', { path: '/:category_id' });
});
```

You can do `{{#link-to "cars.category" "mini"}}`, this will transition to `/cars/mini` url.

You don't need to have `cars/category`. because it's already nested inside `cars` route.
Created [Sample Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/269f0fbd24aff0fab728b3d2a7d5622d?openFiles=router.js%2C) .

For better understanding routing see [AlexSpeller ember-diagonal](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/post)

Comment: Both with and without the suggested changes to the router, I cannot do `{{#link-to "cars.category" "mini"}}`; it will prevent the app from starting, throwing the error: _"Uncaught Error: There is no route named cars.category."_

Comment: @Redsandro Updated answer with ember-twiddle.

Comment: You are right. Routes can indeed be modelled like this. Upvoted because nice example. However, this is unrelated to the problem. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ember 2.11**

Have you try to change the route path to dot notation `cars.category`

A sample nested routes,

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('photos', function(){
    this.route('photo', { path: '/:photo_id' }, function(){
      this.route('comments');
      this.route('comment', { path: '/comments/:comment_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

A proper `link-to` helper link with multiple segements,

```
  {{#link-to 'photo.comment' 5 primaryComment}}
    Main Comment for the Next Photo
  {{/link-to}}
```

You can read more at,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/links/#toc_example-for-multiple-segments